# Cant find the background apps tray in Pop!_OS

Tags: linux

All apps like "Steam", "Slack", "Anydesk" and etc. They were all displaying in black/white in a tray at my panel.

The update for POP!_OS was pending for a few weeks, so "what the heck, let's do this!"...

It was an instant regret when the PC rebooted... all GNOME extensions were GONE! I was not expecting this to happen... =/

I managed to remember most of the extensions I had running before, so I installed [them all](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Gdgs.png).

Didn't take me too much time to realize that the background apps are not showing anymore. They don't show in the dash, nor the panel or anywhere else besides the [System Monitor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oWjGf.png).

The gnome extension Dash to Panel is active, as it may be related I'm posting this [screen shot showing that all possible areas are "Visible"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TaYPW.png).

How can I display the background apps again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, silly me...

I really don't know the reason for it, but seems like the package **https://github.com/ubuntu/gnome-shell-extension-appindicator** was uninstalled during the update.

So the solution for the issue was:

1. Installing this extension: `$sudo apt install gnome-shell-extension-appindicator`
2. Enabling it in the gnome extensions manager: [Ubuntu Appindicators](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Is5we.png)

I hope it helps someone! =)